# ¿Cómo hacer un menú desplegable usando bucles for?

Tags: php, bucle-for

En un post anterior publique una pregunta sobre un bucle, la cual ya fue respuesta por un usuario del foro. Ahora la duda que se me presenta es cómo poder hacer el bucle dentro de sí mismo, para poder hacer una cantidad x de desplegables y a su vez una cantidad z de opciones dentro de cada desplegable.

Adjunto el código que he intentado implementar y no me funciona:

```
  <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-heading">Panel Usuario </div>
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <?php for ($num = 1; $num <= 5; $num++): ?>
    <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Pack de Ejercicios <?= $num ?>
      </button>
    <?php for ($n = 1; $n <= 5; $n++): ?>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ejercicio<?= $n ?></a>
      </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: El código parece correcto. ¿Qué mensaje de error te da o qué resultado obtienes?

Comment: El código php es correcto, pareciera que es el orden de los elementos HTML, por ejemplo, al tener el for para un button, estas replicando el id y no debe ser asi, por otra parte el dropdown menu tambien se esta replicando y pienso que quien debe hacerlo es dropdown item.

Comment: Olvidé que usas bootstrap. Viando el resultado del PHP se ve que el código se genera correctamente el HTML de los `for` anidados, pero la estructura del HTML no es la correcta para un menú anidado. Te dejo en mi respuesta la manera correcta de generar el HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes mal formado el HTML del menú desplegable anidado. Debería ser así:

```
<div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
<div class="sidebar-heading">Panel Usuario </div>
<div class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <?php for ($num = 1; $num <= 5; $num++): ?>
    <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Pack de Ejercicios <?= $num ?>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <?php for ($n = 1; $n <= 5; $n++): ?>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ejercicio<?= $n ?></a>
        <?php endfor; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Es decir, debes meter tantos elementos `<a href="" />` como desees dentro de un `<div class="dropdown-menu">`, y no meter muchos `<div class="dropdown-menu">` con un único `<a href="">`.